# How to print all the last three element of linked list using single loop below is my code which i have used two loop?

Tags: c, singly-linked-list

How to print all the last three element of linked list using single loop below is my code in which i have used two loop? i need to use single loop to print all the last 3 element.please don't mark it as duplicate because this question has be asked but answer is in using two loop.Thanks 
 example
if input is 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 o/p should be 3 2 1?

```
   #include <stdio.h> 
   #include <string.h>
   #include<stdlib.h>
   struct node
   {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
   };

   void add_begin(struct node **ptr,int n)
{
    struct node *temp;
    temp=(struct node* )malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->data=n;
    temp->next=*ptr;
    *ptr=temp;
}

 void display(struct node *ptr)
{
   struct node *prevprev,*prev;
   prevprev=prev=NULL;
   while(ptr->next!=NULL) // here i am getting 3rd last element which is store prevprev
  {
     prevprev=prev;
     prev=ptr;
     ptr=ptr->next;
  }

   while(prevprev)    // from prevprev (i.e last 3rd element ) i m printing till null 
                     //i need to remove this loop and develop a logic in above loop?
  {                  // i am supposed to use single loop?
    printf("%d\n",prevprev->data);
    prevprev=prevprev->next;
  } 
}

main()
{
 struct node *headptr=NULL;
 add_begin(&headptr,1);
 add_begin(&headptr,2);
 add_begin(&headptr,3);
 add_begin(&headptr,4);
 add_begin(&headptr,5);
 add_begin(&headptr,6);
 add_begin(&headptr,7);
 display(headptr);

}
```

Comment: example if input is `1 2 3 4 5 6 7` o/p should be `3 2 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your second loop as you can just print the three values in one go. So change this:

```
   while(prevprev)    // from prevprev (i.e last 3rd element ) i m printing till null 
                     //i need to remove this loop and develop a logic in above loop?
  {                  // i am supposed to use single loop?
    printf("%d\n",prevprev->data);
    prevprev=prevprev->next;
  }
```

to

```
printf("%d\n%d\n%d\n", prevprev->data, prevprev->next->data, prevprev->next->next->data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Run two pointers offset by three nodes thru the list. Once the first pointer reaches the end - start printing nodes pointed by the second pointer.

Answer (score 0):

```
void display(struct node *ptr){
    struct node x1, x2, x3, *curr;
    curr = &x1;
    x1.next = &x2;
    x2.next = &x3;
    x3.next = &x1;
    while(ptr!=NULL){
        curr->data = ptr->data;
        curr = curr->next;
        ptr  = ptr->next;
    }
    for(int i=0; i<3 ;++i, curr=curr->next )
        printf("%d\n", curr->data);
}
```

Comment: sorry but i am supposed to use only single loop,above code has used to loop.

Comment: @user3784175 the way we used to be specified by connecting in the next. E.g `printf("%d\n%d\n%d\n", curr->data,curr->next->data,curr->next->next->data);`